# Is CTRL+M the same as Enter?

Tags: keyboard, whitespace, esoteric-languages, whitespace-language

So, I've recently gotten into Whitespace programming, and one of the characters is listed as `[LF]`. Not knowing what this was(yes, yes, yell at me all you want for being an idiot), I looked it up and found on Wikipedia that it could be typed using `CTRL+M`(aka `^M`). So, I used it for a while, but when I went back and took a look at the article, it said that `LF` is also known as `CRLF`, which is "Carriage Return Line Feed", if I remember correctly. Does this mean that `Enter`, which is technically the "carriage return" works just as well for the newlines? Sorry if this is a stupid question :T

Comment: It depends upon which operating system you are using. If you are on a *nix operating system then you just have `[LF]` whereas on a windows operating system you have `[CRLF]`. I would use enter for new lines though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Carriage return (ascii code 13) and line feed (ascii code 10) are two separate characters. As @EliSadoff said, Windows systems use the CRLF combo to signal the end of a line, while *nix systems use just the LF.

For programming in Whitespace, every interpreter I have used that runs on Windows (including the online ones I've checked) seems to ignore the carriage return character, so you can fairly safely just use the enter key to type LF for Whitespace.

The main difference you would find in using LF instead of CRLF would likely be that if you opened such a text file on Windows (say, in Notepad), the entire contents may be on a single line, since Windows is expecting the CR. Some programs (Notepad++, for example) consider this though and display things properly with either line ending.